# CORS config on angular 7

Tags: angular, cors

Hello I have been struggling with getting the `CORS` to work. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473754/angular-7-app-getting-cors-error-from-angular-client) which I think got me closer, however, I have followed the link in that post to [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy) and used that.

So let me explain my problem, I am createing the proxy:

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxyConfig = [{
  context: '/api',
  target: 'http://localhost:3000',
  secure: false
}];

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig) {
  var proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
  if (proxyServer) {
    var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
    console.log('Using corporate proxy server: ' + proxyServer);
    proxyConfig.forEach(function(entry) {
      entry.agent = agent;
    });
  }
  return proxyConfig;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig);
```

and I am calling `npm start` with the script looking like: `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.js"`but I'm trying to do a post that looks like:

```
let url:string='/api/Acounts/Login';

this.http.post(url, body).subscribe(x=> x.doStuff);
```

I would expect it to call `http://localhost:3000/Accounts/Login` but it is actually calling `http://localhost:42000/api/Accounts/Login`

So my question is why is it calling the incorrect address, and how can i make it call the correct address?

**EDIT:**
I wanted to add `protractor.conf.js` too.

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159168/4078143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking into this for about 2 days, there were multiple issues that i had going on here. The first was that the `MVC` project that I was working with needed a few things to happen.

I needed to add a bit to `WebConfig` file:

```
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
```

and I needed to add to the `GlobalApplication.cs` file.

```
   private void GlobalApplication_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  #if DEBUG
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            Response.End();
            return;
        }
  #endif
    }
```

Hope this helps others!

Comment: This is something that I also ran into recently with a Vue application. Our webserver setups are a little different but you might also need to handle the following situations. I ran into these issues on an NGINX server: I had to manually specify a `204` response for all `OPTIONS` preflight requests. I also found that my origin headers didn't account for `4xx` responses and had to ensure that it would always be set (NGINX has an `always` flag). Hopefully this helps, but might be irrelevant to your specific case.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't noticed anything yet, but I will keep that in mind.